# Find orthogonal complement with some constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab, numerical-linear-algebra

Let's suppose I have a matrix $B_{m \times n}$.

I have to find K matrices $m \times r$, where r is not necessarily the same for all the matrices ($r=r(k)$), $A_k$ to follow these two conditions:

- $row(B) \perp row(A_k) \quad \forall k=1,..,K$
- $\bigcap _{k=1}^Krow(A_k)= \{0 \} \quad $ where 0 is the zero vector.

I've to implement a code where the requirements for the matrices are the one above.

What I thought to do is to get the complete orthogonal complement of matrix B and take the required r columns to create the $A_k$ matrices, but then I have no guarantee that the second requirement holds! I'm not sure this is the right way to approach the problem.

In Matlab, to get the orthogonal complement I would write `null(B')`

Comment: If $A_k$ is a matrix, then what do you mean by $\bigcap _{k=1}^K(A_k)$?

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to write $row(A_k)$

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you're doing that results in an empty intersection?

Comment: I want to explore the variation structure among different dataset through the  score sub-spaces.
Suppose I have K datasets $X_k$, I 'm looking for two matrices for each dataset where I can rewrite $X_k = B + A_k$ (+ noise matrix). I want B to identify the common score subspace among the datasets and $A_k$ to be the individual matrices, in the sense that they are orthogonal to  $row(B)$ and the intersection of their score subspaces is the zero vector space.
So, the intersection means  that there is no non-trivial common row pattern in every individual score subspaces across the datasets

Comment: I'm in the early stage of implementation where I have to initialize matrices $B$ and $A_k$ to have the properties mentioned above

Comment: That doesn't answer the question that I'm asking, which I'm hoping has a quick answer. You set "I get an empty intersection". Presumably, that means that you generated matrices $A_k$ and somehow concluded that the intersection of their rowspaces is empty.  How did you generate those matrices? How did you conclude that the intersection was empty?

Comment: I realized my conclusion was wrong. I will edit my question, thank you for letting me realize it. Anyway, I really don't know how to fulfil both the requirements at the same time; first of all, I would like to understand how to approach a problem like that on paper, then I will figure it out how to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following steps will allow you to generate matrices $A_k$ satisfying the given requirements:

- Find a matrix $M$ whose columns form a basis for the kernel of $B$ (for instance, we can take `M = null(B)` in matlab)
- Partition the columns of the matrix $M$ into submatrices $M_k$. That is, take
  $$
  M = \pmatrix{M_1 & M_2 & \cdots & M_K}.
  $$
  The size of these matrices is not important. If $K$ is larger than the number of columns in $M$, then set any remaining $M_k$ to be the scalar quantity zero.
- For all $k$, set $A_k = M_k'P_k$, where $P_k$ is any choice of $n_k \times r(k)$ matrix. $n_k$ denotes the number of columns in $M_k$.

Comment: @Virginie It's a bit that you haven't answered my question. As far as your second comment goes, I have no clue what a "score subspace is". That said, if you're sufficiently clear about what exactly the problem is, then I guess I don't need to know that. Hopefully this answer gives you what you're looking for.